# Set up class to have a variable that can be used across document

Tags: macros

I know I can create a new command like so:

```
 \newcommand{\myname}{John Doe}
```

`\myname` would then display "John Doe",
However I would like to be able to do something more dynamic like the fallowing

```
\newcomand{\name[2]}{@firstname}{@secondname}
\newcomand{\makename}{\name}
```

So I would want `\name{John}{Doe}` to "save the variable"
and then `\makename` would display the name "John Doe".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could be after

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setname}[2]{%
  \gdef\@firstname{#1}% First name
  \gdef\@lastname{#2}% Last name
}
\newcommand{\printname}{%
  \ifdef{\@firstname}{\ifdefempty{\@firstname}{}{\@firstname\ }}{}%
  \ifdef{\@lastname}{\ifdefempty{\@lastname}{\unskip}{\@lastname}{}}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
My name is \printname.

\setname{John}{Doe}%
My name is \printname.

\setname{}{Cares}%
My name is \printname.

\setname{Jane}{}%
My name is \printname.
\end{document}
```

The above approach is very similar to what `\title`, `\author` and `\date` enforces for titles. Some checks are made to ensure that empty elements don't insert unnecessary spaces.

Comment: If its not too much trouble could describe why you added all the \ifdef statements?

Comment: @Howard: `\ifdef` checks whether `\@firstname` (or `\@lastname`) exists, while `\ifdefempty` checks whether the definition is empty/blank. Based on these conditionals it avoids printing a space if it is not necessary. If you remove these conditionals and just print/use `\@firstname\ \@lastname`, an unnecessary space will be printed if you have either a blank `\@firstname` or `\@lastname` or both.

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many names as you want; the macro `\name` if called without optional argument will define `\firstname`, `\secondname` and `\printname`; if called like

```
\name[suffix]{A}{B}
```

will define `\firstnamesuffix`, `\secondnamesuffix` and `\printnamesuffix`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for printing |
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\name}[3][]{%
  \csgdef{firstname#1}{#2}%
  \csgdef{secondname#1}{#3}%
  \csxdef{printname#1}{%
    \ifblank{#3}%
      {\unexpanded{#2}}%
      {\ifblank{#2}{\unexpanded{#3}}{\unexpanded{#2 #3}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\name{John}{Doe}

|\printname|\firstname|\secondname|

\name[p]{Plato}{}

|\printnamep|\firstnamep|\secondnamep|

\name[x]{}{\'X}

|\printnamex|\firstnamex|\secondnamex|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What do you need is the basic principle of TeX. It is able to define and redefine macros.

```
\def\makename{}
\def\name#1#2{\def\makename{#1 #2}}

Now, \makename\ is empty.
\name{John}{Doe}
Now, \makename\ expands to the declared name.
```